# Sketch: How to select only the contents of selected artboards

Tags: sketch-app

I'd like to be able to make a selection of artboards (let's say 20 of them), and make Sketch select **only the objects** inside of them, as opposed to artboards and objects together.
It's for changing a layer style of that objects.
The result would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> while doing a selection with your mouse will result selecting only objects (ignoring Artboards and Groups).